# python script returns multiple data, how to get the first data and download it

Tags: python

My script is

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
url = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")

headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   auth=auth
)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

And get the response body, the format as below:

```
{
        "startAt":0
        "comment":[
            {
                "self": "xxxx",
                "id": "xxx",
                "body": "daily in URLlink"
            },
            {
                "self": "xxxx",
                "id": "xxx",
                "body": "daily in URLlink"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

And I need to get the first data in the comment(The URLlink in the body).

The URLlink is download link, I want to download the URLlink content automatically by script.

**Update1**

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
url = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")

headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   auth=auth
)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))

url = responsed["comment"][0]["body"]

r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

open('file_name', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

And get the error:

[image]

Then I add `import responsed`, get the latest error.

**Update2**

Now, update the python script, it as below:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
#import responsed

url = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("email@example.com", "api_token")

headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   auth=auth
)

#print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))

url = response.json()['comments'][0]["body"]
```

And it response body format like:

```
daily build in URLDownloadLink
```

Before this, I need to click `URLDownloadLink` download it.

And now, I want to achieve automatic download. Thx

Comment: can you try `response.json()['comment'][0]`

Comment: Not work, please check the update1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

change `url = responsed["comment"][0]["body"]` to

```
url = response["comment"][0]["body"]
```

```
response = {
        "startAt":0,
        "comment":[
            {
                "self": "xxxx",
                "id": "xxx",
                "body": "daily in URLlink"
            },
            {
                "self": "xxxx",
                "id": "xxx",
                "body": "daily in URLlink"
            },
        ]
    }

url = responsed["comment"][0]["body"]


#download (many option):

import requests

r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

open('file_name', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Hi, I got some issue, please check the update1

Comment: use use responsed instead of response @VitoLiu

Comment: Hi, I have update the question, please check the update2, in the latest response body, the format like `daily build in URLDownloadLink`, and I just need the `URLDownloadLink` to download it. Thanks

Comment: Hi, how to get the response body last value.